# Can't figure out why I'm getting the typeError 'unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str' '

Tags: python

I posted 15 mins ago about this problem but was told there wasn't enough code to tell what the problem was so I've included the whole thing this time.

The problem is in the self.__r_miles += (new_odo - self.__odometer) line in the process_rental function. I know that based off the error and the specific line, self.__odometer is a string. But for the life of me I cannot figure out why. I'm assuming it's something obvious but I've just been staring at it for too long to notice.

I believe I've put everything in as an int whenever I need to but obviously I messed up somewhere.

```
 class Fleet(object):
    fleetcount = 0
    car_desc = "DMC DeLorean"
    daily_rate = 100
    maxfleet = 10
    
    def get_vin(self):
        return self.__vin
    def get_year(self):
        return self.__year
    def get_odometer(self):
        return self.__odometer
    def set_odometer(self, miles):
        if miles>self.__odometer:
            self.__odometer = miles
    def get_r_miles(self):
        return self.__r_miles
    def get_r_days(self):
        return self.__r_days
    def get_rentals(self):
        return self.__rentals
    
    def __init__(self, vin, typ, year, color, odometer, r_miles = 0, r_days = 0, rentals = 0 ):
        self.__vin = vin
        self.__type = typ
        self.__year = year
        self.color = color
        self.__odometer = odometer
        self.__r_miles = r_miles
        self.__r_days = r_days
        self.__rentals = rentals
        Fleet.fleetcount += 1
        
    def process_rental(self, new_odo, days):
        self.__rentals += 1
        self.__r_days += days
        self.__r_miles += (new_odo - self.__odometer)
        self.set_odometer(new_odo)
        
    def calc_bill(self,new_odo, days): 
        return days * Fleet.daily_rate
    
    def calc_age(self, curr_yr):
        age = curr_yr - self.__year
        return age
    
    def sell_car(self,curr_yr):
        if self.calc_age(curr_yr)>3 or self.__odometer>50000:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        
    def print_summary(self):
        print("VIN:", self.__vin, "Make:",Fleet.car_desc, "Year:", self.__year, "Color:", self.color, "Odometer:", self.__odometer, "\n")
        
    def print_metrics(self, curr_yr):
        age = curr_yr - self.__year
        rmpy = self.__r_miles/age
        rdpy = self.__r_days/age
        rpy = self.__rentals/age
        mpr = self.__r_miles/self.__rentals
        dpr = self.__r_days/self.__rentals
        print("METRICS FOR CAR WITH VIN", self.__vin, "ARE AS FOLLOWS")
        print("Average rental miles per year:", rmpy)
        print("Average rental days per year:", rdpy)
        print("Average times rented per year:", rpy)
        print("Average miles per rental:", mpr)
        print("Average days per rental:", dpr, "\n")
    
    def fleet_left(self):
        remaining = Fleet.maxfleet - Fleet.fleetcount
        if remaining>0:
            return remaining
        else:
            return 0
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__vin + "," + self.__type + "," + self.__year + "," + self.__odometer + "," + self.color + "," + self.__r_miles + "," + self.__r_days + "," + self.__rentals
        
class Truck(Fleet):
    daily_rate = 85
    mile_rate = .5
    def calc_bill(self, new_odo, days): 
        miles = new_odo - self.__odometer
        return (miles * Truck.mile_rate) + (days * Truck.daily_rate)


with open("fleet.txt", "r") as myfile:
    next(myfile)
    fleet = {}
    for line in myfile:
         v, ty, y, o, c, rm, rd, r = line.strip().split(",")
         if ty == "C":
            fleet[v] = Fleet(v, ty, int(y), int(o), c, int(rm), int(rd), int(r))
         else:
            fleet[v] = Truck(v, ty, int(y), int(o), c, int(rm), int(rd), int(r))

totalrev = 0
with open("transaction.txt", "r") as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        trans = line.strip().split(",")
        if trans[1] == "R":
            totalrev += fleet[trans[0]].calc_bill(int(trans[2]), int(trans[3]))
            fleet[trans[0]].process_rental(int(trans[2]), int(trans[3]))
        elif trans[1] == "S":
            fleet[trans[0]].set_odometer(int(trans[2]))
        elif trans[1] == "P":
            fleet[trans[0]].color = trans[2]
            
yr = int(input("What is the current year? "))
sell_list = []
for obj in fleet:
    if obj.sell_car(yr) == True:
        sell_list.append(obj.get_vin())

rem = Fleet.fleet_left()

print("Total Revenue:", totalrev)
print("VINs of vehicles that should be sold:", sell_list)
print("Additional number of vehicles that can be acquired:", rem)

with open("updated_fleet.txt", "w") as myfile:
    for obj in fleet:
        outline = obj.__str__()
        myfile.write(outline)
    myfile.close()
```

Comment: Means what it says: You're trying to subtract a string from an integer. Subtraction only makes sense when both things are numbers.

Comment: (`s.split()` returns _strings_; it doesn't return numbers, so you need to be sure any part of it you reference is cast to a number before you use it).

Comment: Granted, in the code given you're casting things to `int`s, but without a [mre] we can run ourselves without changes to see the problem on our own machines, it's hard to trust the assertion that the code shown is the _only_ code involved in creating the issue.

Comment: You know what the line is, and the error says the problem is subtracting an int and str, so `self.__odometer` is a str. The only place where `process_rental` is called is `fleet[trans[0]].process_rental`, so `fleet[trans[0]].__odometer` is a str. You don't show us how that object is made or when it's put into `fleet`, so we can't say for sure how that happened

Comment: `self.__odometer` is a string.

Comment: So I'm aware that the problem is that self.__odometer is a string, but I just can't figure out why it's not an int. I've edited the question to show my full code. Appreciate any help!

Comment: `fleet[v] = Fleet(v, ty, int(y), int(o), c, int(rm), int(rd), int(r))` You aren't putting `int()` around `c`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you're saying produces an error

```
self.__r_miles += (new_odo - self.__odometer)
```

Specifically

```
new_odo - self.__odometer
```

And the error is:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'
```

This means that `self.__odometer` is a string. So you have either:

- Initialized it to a string value
- Changed its value to a string somewhere

Check the parts of your code that sets `self.__odometer` and make sure that the assigned value is always int. You might not have casted something to int e.g. something like `self.__odometer = trans[0]` instead of `self.__odometer = int(trans[0])`.

This is the source of the error.

```
v, ty, y, o, c, rm, rd, r = line.strip().split(",")
if ty == "C":
    fleet[v] = Fleet(v, ty, int(y), int(o), c, int(rm), int(rd), int(r))
else:
    fleet[v] = Truck(v, ty, int(y), int(o), c, int(rm), int(rd), int(r))
#                                           ^ You didn't cast the 5th argument, which is for odometer
```

The `line.strip().split(",")` produces strings. Then, you just directly used it to initialize `odometer` which is the 5th argument:

```
class Fleet:
    def __init__(self, vin, typ, year, color, odometer, r_miles = 0, r_days = 0, rentals = 0 ):
        #                                     ^ 5th argument
```

You only passed the string `c`. Instead, cast it to int first `int(c)`.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'm aware that the problem is that self.__odometer is a string, but I just can't figure out why it's not an int, even after double checking the whole code. I've edited the question to show my full code. Appreciate any help!

Comment: I updated my answer. In summary, you should change your instantiation of `Fleet` and `Truck` to use `int(c)` instead of just `c`. Could you check if it works now?

Comment: Wow, just as I suspected, it was something very obvious! - in one place I had odometer 4th and in the other I had it 5th.

Comment: One other thing if you don't mind - after I fixed that it now gives me an attribute error " 'str' object has no attribute 'sell_car' " in the following block of code

Comment: the pasting of code in here didn't work, but it's the 14th line from the bottom

Comment: It is because `fleet` is a dictionary. Then when you iterated over it `for obj in fleet:`, this will iterate over the string keys of the dictionary. Seems like what you need are not the string keys but the Fleet values. So change that loop into `for obj in fleet.values():`. Does it work?

Comment: I figured it out a different way before I saw this, but thanks very much for the help!

Comment: Glad it helped :) If it's all the answer you need, you might want to accept it as the answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: The only thing I have a problem with now is that I am trying to write the new/updated values for each of the objects into a txt file on different lines, values separated by commas. I'm attempting to do this with the very last block of the code, as well as the __str__ function. However, the only thing that is going into the new txt file is VINs for the two vehicles. They are not on different lines or separated by commas - it is just '101102'